# SQL Compact(sdf) создает копию

Tags: c#, sql

Программа выполняет инсерты и есть датасет.
В какой-то момент появляется "база (1).sdf"
Причем отловить никак не могу, запускал и кучу окон и другие возможные глючные случаи создавал - никак. 
Однако иногда по закрытию, смотрю, лежит копия. Причем заполненая - эдакий полный бейкап :) Ещё и с новыми данными (что самое плохое), а основная остается без последних изменений :(

Comment: _"Причем отловить никак не могу,"_ -- у вас код программы есть? если нет, то можете открыть сборку в Reflector'е или [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

Comment: Да, код мой. Всё сам писал, просто он появляется в моментах, необъяснимых. Повторить на брякпойнтах не удается :(

Comment: Возможно это важно, база расположена на yandex disk и используется с нескольких компьютеров, но вряд-ли одновременно. Сделал для себя и жены домашнюю бухгалтерию. Если надо могу вынести код на github.

Comment: _"Если надо могу вынести код на github"_ -- хорошо. посмотрю.

Comment: [ссылка](https://github.com/SergeyToff/Home-Storage)
Правда там очень корявый код, не готовил его к паблику, извините.

Comment: Ответ яндекса: "Дело в том, что при редактировании файлов (включая файлы из Вашего примера), программы создают рядом с исходным файлом его копию с внесенными изменениями, а затем удаляют первоначальный файл. В этот момент Диск синхронизирует оба варианта файла и более свежему присваивает номер, чтобы избежать конфликта. Мы со своей стороны уже работаем над исправлением ситуации. А пока я могу порекомендовать Вам отключать синхронизацию на время работы с файлами."

Comment: только сейчас увидел коммент и ссылку. надо было поставить @Stack перед ним, чтобы мне пришло уведомление. _"Ответ яндекса"_ -- т.е. проблема решена?

Comment: не особо то и решена, скорее убежал от нее. Но в чем-то они правы. Отследить не удалось. Сделал сервис для дома, захожу вношу всё через сайт. Тобишь правит одна программа главного компа, этим исключил возможность появления копии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server Compact - локальная база данных. Как я понял из комментариев, есть папка, которая синхронизирована с хостингом. В этой папке находится файл с базой данных.
Когда в программе происходит изменение базы данных, Sql Server Compact записывает изменения в файл базы данных, а модуль синхронизации пытается копировать изменившийся файл на хостинг, но из-за того, что в программе открыто соединение с базой данных, модуль синхронизации создает копию. В итоге получается два файла базы данных.
В такой ситуации, после запуска программы, файл базы данных можно копировать, например, в папку c:\temp, а во время завершения программы, копировать файл обратно в папку, синхронизированную с хостингом.

Comment: Практически верно. Однако с ситуацией в темп, можно затереть чужие данные ненароком. В остальном ситуация верна и найдено решение. Всем участвующим спасибо.

Comment: `%temp%` и `c:\temp` - это разные папки. `%temp%` транслируется в `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`